# Count number of dynamically generated list element in an unordered list

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery

I have a menu that is generated from an XML file. The XML file is loaded using AJAX. The only html in the menu that is hard coded is:

```
<div id="leftNav">
    <ul class="level1">
    </ul>
</div>
```

the rest of the menu is dynamically created based on the contents of the XML file. In the Chrome inspector all the list elements that should be in the menu are there. Now when I try to count the number of list elements I get 0. I figure it's because there are no list elements hard coded on the page. The code I use to do the counting is:

```
alert($('.level1 > li').size());
```

which alerts 0.

EDIT- i misplaced the function call and the xml had not finished loading. the code does work as expected.

The function that parses the XML and generates the extra list items runs before I try to count the list items.

Any ideas as to how to get the number of list items?

Comment: if there really are `li nodes`, this should work as expected.

Comment: I admit to voting this up primarily in support of your username.

Comment: Check this out. I made a fiddle that adds <li>s dynamically and counts them correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/DJTXN/1/ So it should be able to count okay in your case too as long as the import is in face before the count.

Comment: how are you inserting the LIs? http://www.jsfiddle.net/mgrum/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ".length" not ".size()"

```
alert($('.level1 > li').length);
```

*edit* — apparently I'm hilariously wrong here but I'd give ".length" a shot anyway :-)  Also make sure your script isn't dropping in extraneous crap around the list of `<li>` elements - try changing the selector so that it's just ".level1 li" and see if that changes anything.

Comment: `.size()` is available since jQuery.. ohh 1.0.0 :) ?

Comment: the jQuery doc for .size() does encourage the use of .length, though.

Comment: @WesP: I'm not encouraging anybody to use `.size()`, I'm just saying its totally legit and available for a long time.

Comment: oh well oops then.  I'd definitely try it with `.length` out of superstition :-)

Comment: i should have mentioned i've tried both size and length and both return 0

Comment: Well in that case, I think you may want to check to make sure the markup being stuffed into the `<ul>` really is nothing more than a list of `<li>` elements.

Comment: turns out i misplaced the function call and it was trying to count before the xml has finished parsing

Answer (score 0):

You should learn about DOM because `.length` or `size()` are counting the `li` items and there's no `li` in the loaded DOM.

It has been dynamically added after the loading of the page. You should add an event handler on a button or something with the help of the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function